# Migrating from SiteEdit to Experience manager

Tags: experience-manager, siteedit

We are already using SiteEdit 2009 SP3 in tridion 2011 sp1 which has dwt, vb script compound templates for pages and components. We are planning to migrate to tridion 2013 sp1 and Experince manager as well. How different is exeprience manager from SiteEdit? What are the points to be considered for migrating from SiteEdit to Experience Manager? How complex would this migration be keeping installation as out of scope? Whether existing siteedit span tags need to changed or not?

Update: Is SieEdit 2009 SP3 compatible with Tridion 2013 SP1?

Comment: You do *not* have to change your existing markup or even templates to make XPM work. I'll post a follow-up answer.

Answer (score 3):

Experience Manager is integrated with SDL Tridion 2013 so you won't need to do a separate installation. Also, from configuration perspective, XPM is much simpler as compared to Site Edit. Regarding site edit span tags, templates etc. they need to be changed. You can refer below link (login required) to see step by step process for setting up XPM:

[Experience Manager](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13)

In my personal opinion, setting up XPM is much simpler as compared to Site Edit (Except the Session Preview feature of XPM ;)), but it is much more powerful and seamless than Site Edit.

I have written [THIS](http://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/sdl-tridion-experience-manager-xpm-vs-sdl-tridion-content-manager-explorer-cme/) blog which may help you somewhat on understanding the power of XPM.

**Update:** [HERE](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-7B860C39-575F-49B3-8BDE-2AE409D52CD7&addHistory=true&query=Siteedit&scope=&tid=68d8d59a-3061-41f2-b13e-7b4365a49666&filename=GUID-7B860C39-575F-49B3-8BDE-2AE409D52CD7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-7B860C39-575F-49B3-8BDE-2AE409D52CD7&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DSiteedit&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1405412622900&currentQuery=Siteedit&currentScope=) is the official documentation for upgrading from SiteEdit to XPM

Comment: Is SieEdit 2009 SP3 compatible with Tridion 2013 SP1?

Comment: I would recommend you adding a fresh question for the same as this query might not be visible to most of the community

Comment: ok Pankaj, will do it with additional doubts.

Answer (score 2):

XPm is entirely new experience and provide lots of features, i will suggest to search [blogs](http://www.netwhisperer.com/2012/10/31/sdl-tridion-new-user-interface-2012-overview/) (this link is for ui-2012) but features are similar + XPM 13 has few new features like 'Switch Device’

**Your old site-edit tags will not work**, You have to include new OutOfTheBox TemplateBuildingBlocks in your Component template and in page template to generate new tags. Please refer following link 
[Experience Manager implementation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_ImplTopics6C1CA85145E9495FAB063988DE773A48)(Requires Login)

While moving from SiteEdit to UI-2012(older version of Xpm) we faced following issues.

1. There were Div overlapping issues on 40% of the site, we had to do lots of css/html structure changes for that. this may varies site to site.
2. Changing all those PTs and CTs for including new tbbs, because we were directly using the tbb, so i will suggest create compound template to wrap the xpm tbbs and include those on your PTs & CTs
3. There are changes in User-experience also, so editor need some training.

Answer (score 0):

At the *minimum* (though maybe not ideal), when adding Experience Manager to an existing VBScript setup, you need to:

1. Add the new **bootstrap script reference:**

   `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
   defer="defer" src="http://<cme-hostname>/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js"
   id="tridion.siteedit"></script>`
2. Republish templates per the [Documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-4DC6B16E-D200-4432-AAE9-B3CBC3339322).

Credit to SDL Product Management and R&D for making this compatible as this was a big question for "legacy" setups.

*I understand the old VBScript Site-Edit tags were missing time-stamps, so I'm not sure if Session Preview will work out of the box, but that's a separate question.*

You probably *should* eventually move to Modular Templating, but this could be done over time. Upgrading to Experience Manager doesn't require a complete template rewrite.

Comment: We also have similar setup.  Only change is that we are using modular templates and have our own TBB added at CT level which is outputting required Siteedit tags (start component presentation and start component field) at PT level we are using OOTB TBB "enable inline editing for page". If we upgrade to tridion 2013 sp1 with XPM can we continue with our customized TBB, we will upgrade PT level TBB to XPM manager.

Comment: If your start CP and start field output matches the JSON format, then your customized TBB for CTs should work with the same caveat on Session Preview. For modular templating on DWT, you can opt to use the newer calls (`FieldStartMarker()`).

Comment: Thanks, we are reading almost all fields in .net assembly and at that time only we are adding SiteEdit tags around it.  Yes we will make sure that SiteEdit tags are matching with Experience manager's required format.